# any good Javascript SQLite connection APIs?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, proxy

I need to access a SQLite database from a (webbrowser, chrome and firefox specifically) javascript app, and execute queries from javascript (well, i could make a hugeass API frontend too, but why bother.. the clients are trusted); is there any good javascript->SQLite db api/framework/whatever-you-wanna-call-it that i could/should use?  or should i just wrap up a simple (php, if i'd do it) query proxy with XMLHttpRequest/WebSocket? 
(PS: i believe emscripten/SQL.js is not a viable alternative, as i need to save the database between sessions and being able to open the database from other places than the javascript VM, and it uses a huge amount of memory compared to native sqlite, and is much slower when the DB grows~)

Comment: chrome has websql built-in, but i think you need a php to ajax bridge.

Comment: yeah. i need to be able to access the database from other sources than the Javascript VM as well. and i don't want to dig too deep into the chrome/V8 API's, maybe it'd be possible, but way more work and complexity than it's worth :p also add that the WebSQL will probably be deprecated and removed in future versions.

Comment: well it's already deprecated, but i doubt it will be removed anytime soon, a lot of folks like it.

Comment: hmm, why would anyone prefer the (deprecated and mostly unsupported) WebSQL over the (portable and supported) emscripten/sql.js though? the resource issues maybe?

Comment: emscripten stuff is huge and slows down the page, whereas webSQL is nearly ubiquitous on mobile (http://caniuse.com/#feat=sql-storage), persists larger amounts of data than localStorage, needs no libraries, and is well-documented and understood. i don't use it, but if i did, that'd be why.